# @Primary and @Profile does not work to override a Bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring project to run (aka PA) which has a dependency with other project (PB) and this one has dependency with other project (PC)
PB is a customization of PC actually.

The problem is that my PA uses a different database model than PC was originally designed. Within PC there is a @Configuration class with a @Bean is recovered querying database

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfig {

  @Bean
  public Map<Long, String> translatedActivationStatusMap(ActivationStatusRepository activationStatusRepository,
      TranslationUtil translationUtil) {
    return activationStatusRepository.findActivationStatusBusinessCodes()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ActivationStatusRow::getId, activationStatusRow -> {
          final String translatedPrimaryStatus = translationUtil
              .getTranslation(activationStatusRow.getStatusPrimaryBusinessCode(), activationStatusRow.getStatusPrimaryDescription());
          final String translatedSecondaryStatus = translationUtil
              .getTranslation(activationStatusRow.getStatusSecondaryBusinessCode(), activationStatusRow.getStatusSecondaryDescription());
          return String.format("%s - %s", translatedPrimaryStatus, translatedSecondaryStatus);
        }));
  }
}
```

As the table quered by the upper repository method does not exists in the DB configured in PA, it throws an exception:

> table or view does not exists

My idea to resolve it is avoid Spring try to load such bean in the context. To do it I have tried several options but any of them worked.

**Option 1**: create a new class in PB and annotate it as @Configuration and a method to return same type annotated as a @Bean and @Primary. But didn't work. Same exception raised

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfigSecond {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public Map<Long, String> translatedActivationStatusMapSecond(ActivationStatusRepository activationStatusRepository,
                                                         TranslationUtil translationUtil) {
    return new HashMap<>();
  }
}
```

**Option 2**: same class annotated with @Profile("test") and set the property "spring.profiles.active=test" in the application properties. Didn't work :(

Does anybody figure out why @Primary does not override the method?
What do you think it could solve my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you specify, how are you importing the dependencies in the projects?
Like `private final Map<Long, String> translatedActivationStatus`

Comment: They are maven dependency. Above are the piece of code of the method bean (the inherited exsiting and the created). Both are public and no final.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea. Execute @bean method is within runtime. It executes the first bean. If another with @Primary is found spring override the object. But the method with the @Bean is always executed even there is another with @Primary returning the same type of object.

Definitly @Primary won't fix my problem and likely I must to keep on with the profile strategy.

Answer (score 0):

### CoreConfigSecond is ignored

Your PB is ignored. Please code CoreConfigSecond  as the first configuration and im `CoreConfigSecond` @ImportConfig the config from PC.